# Why is $ \mathrm{Spec} \ A [T_1 , \dots , T_n ] \to \mathrm{Proj} \ A [T_0 , \dots , T_n ] $ an embedding?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, projective-schemes, affine-schemes

Let $ A $ be a commutative ring with identity.

I would like to know how to establish that : $ \mathrm{Spec} \ A [T_1 , \dots , T_n ] \to \mathrm{Proj} \ A [T_0 , \dots , T_n ] $ is an embedding ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What's the map?

Comment: $ \mathrm{Proj} A [ T_0 , \dots , T_n ] = \{ \ \text{ homogenous prime ideals } \ \mathfrak{p} \subset A [T_0 , \dots , T_n ] \ | \ \mathfrak{p} \ \text{ doesnt contain} \ A [T_0 , \dots , T_n ]_{+} \ \} $. Absolutly, I mean an open embedding like in complex geometry.  :-D

Comment: $ \mathrm{Proj} A [T_0 , \dots , T_n ] = \displaystyle \bigcup_{ i = 0 }^{n} D ( T_i ) $, and : $ D(T_i) = \mathrm{Spec} \Big( A [ T_ 0 , ... , T_n  , \dfrac{1}{ T_{i} } ]_0 \Big) $ ... That's all what i can tell you about what i think. Could you help me a little more please ?  :-D

Comment: Your $D(T_i)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{A}^n_A$. Do you see why it's true? Does that answer the question? It's probably bad to have $T_i$ in both the source and target here: for the map I'm envisioning they don't really get mapped to one another.

Comment: I don't really know why $ D(T_i ) \simeq \mathbb{A}_{A}^n $. Can you help me again please ?

Comment: Thank you. :-) In fact, i prefer to look for another proof using homogenous prime ideals of $ A [T_0 , \dots , T_n ] $. Is it possible ? In other words, il prefer having an algebraic proof, instead of a topological proof.

Comment: If you try to prove something is an open immersion, this is a topological statement. Somehow it doesn't make sense to say that you want an algebraic proof. But at any rate, I think most constructions that show that $\operatorname{Proj} A[T_0,\ldots,T_n]$ is a scheme will at some point identify $D(T_i)$ with $\operatorname{Spec} A[T_0,\ldots,T_n, \tfrac{1}{T_i}]_0$, to even define the structure sheaf! (Actually, Hartshorne does it slightly differently, but immediately proves a very general statement about $D(f)$.)